# What is the best method of .Net for access very large database?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oledb

Suppose that, I use Oracle database. If my table have a lot of data about 10k records. When I use OleDB to select data from that table in ASP.NET. It's very slow.

Is there any methods that better than OleDB Oracle client?

Comment: How come it's slow? Do you need the 10k records at once? Are indexes defined correctly?

Comment: Who is going to read 10k records client side?!  Paginate that...

Comment: 10k records is not very big at all. Please post some of your code and queries and what "slow" means for you.

Comment: Why the hell are you even reading 10K records at once.. it can be too much data across the wire.. read them in chunks. like maximum of 50 records at once..

Comment: suppose that, because I wanna use 10k records to calculate data in each record to get some result and this calculate method cannot done by SQL statement.

Comment: @Noppol read about Oracle Analytical functions. Can't do that .... I don't believe that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing 10k rows is not much. If it is for analytical reasons that you want to make calculations based on the data, use Oracle Analytical functions. They are VERY powerfull. By the time you accessed all rows and passed them to the client to have the analysis done on the client, the analysis has already been done by Oracle.
Do the analysis as close to where your data is as possible: in the rdbms.

See
[Dan's library](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html)
[Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm)
[ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3170642805938)

Comment: +1 too many people don't even think about doing calcs on the db itself, rather they see it as a dumping ground of raw data that needs to be sucked out into some java/.net/whatever client to then be "processed".

Comment: yes, it's a pity that the power of the rdbms on this point is underestimated. Thanks tbone.

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) is a native implementation.